# Android 6.0 bug ? Have permission but getScanResults() still return empty list in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have request the permission in android version 6.0 - Marshmallow,But it still return empty list when using getScanResults().

```
 private boolean checkPermission() {

    List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

After request permission, then in the onRequestPermissionsResult method,I have get the permission of ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, But I still can not the scan result

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            if (permissions.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    (permissions.length == 2 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                            grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                List<ScanResult> scanResults = mWifi.getScanResults();
                //list is still empty
            }
             else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(mContext, getString(R.string.permission_deny), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Is this a bug of android M?

Comment: have you called `mWifi.startScan();`  ?

Comment: yes, I called the startScan()  in onResume:

Comment: Did you wait for [SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION) broadcast?

Comment: Yes, I did , I called the method: checkPermission() when I receive the SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION broadcast

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You still need to enable WIFI after you request the permission. So in short, you have to do this in sequence for scanning the perimeter:

1. Request the necessary permissions (**ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION**). Additionally, on MM you need to request this at run-time, as you stated.
2. **Enable WIFI** with WifiManager#setWifiEnabled(true);
3. You **don't** have to enable location access programatically that I know off. ***But read the note below***.
4. You have to register a BrodcastReceiver for **SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION**. This is where you **get the signal that the scans are ready**. Doesn't matter if you register through AndroidManifest or dynamically at run-time, as long as it's done before the next step.
5. You have to WifiManager#**startScan()** in order to request **exactly ONE** update for network scans. If you want more, set up a **timer/timertask** (recommended) or reschedule when you receive the previous one (which might never come)
6. Only on the BroadcastReceiver onReceive will you be able to call WifiManager#getScanResults() ***with plausible results***.

Note: On some phones (Moto X 2014), I noticed you need **basic location enabled** to get any results, which only the user (system UI) seems to be able to do trigger on/off. If the user has location completely off, I can't seem to get a non-empty result list, **even though the system UI can**. This is likely due to Marshmallow needs to have location for Bluetooth and WiFi scans in user apps, and a bad implementation by Motorola, or a defect already fixed in latest Marshmallow bug tracker but not in Motorola's latest OTA, because this doesn't happen in a Nexus 5 or a Galaxy S6.

Comment: I didn't find anything in the docs about the need for an ACCESS_WIFI_STATE permission. Is it mentioned somewhere?

Comment: likely not. I added it for good measure but CHANGE_WIFI_STATE likely comes with the former permission attached from hierarchy

Comment: CHANGE_WIFI_STATE isn't mentioned either in the docs. And its actually not even needed when the user switches his wifi on manually. IMO your answer should also mention that fact.

Comment: @leRobot - just noticed that startScan() is soon to be deprecated

Comment: yeah, I kinda expected this and more while reading Android P behavior changes for sensor access: https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#input-data-privacy 

In short, all apps accessing sensors will likely need a foreground service... OTOH, they are providing a Wifi RTT API, which might make cases of RSSI retrieval moot. On my original problem though - making a custom Wifi manager - it will likely deprecate original code. Luckily I don't support that app anymore, so it's someone else's problem. Still scummy of G to cut access to Wifi - it's becoming a walled Garden

Answer (score 4):

on nexus 5, with M update, it appears to me I also need to have GPS location turned on to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it cause by android M's runtime permission management,you can set targetSdkVersion 19(less than 21 or 23) to try again. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

In Android Marshmallow 6.0.1 go to Settings > Connections and hold down Location. There click on Location method and you will see three options:

- High accuracy: uses GPS, Wi-Fi and mobile networks.
- Battery saving: uses Wi-Fi and mobile networks.
- Device only: uses GPS.

Select ***Battery saving*** in order to get Wi-Fi scan results without enabling GPS.

Answer (score 0):

The permission is requested when needed at run-time. Note that it is NOT:

```
Settings -> Location
```

It is checking:

```
Settings -> Applications -> (YOUR APP) -> Permissions
```

That is where the more granular run-time permission must be set.  It must be set for each application as of version 6.