# Scanning APs - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I tried to learn how to develop an Apps for scanning Access Points. I read many references and watched many videos. Among them are the following:
[Android 6.0 bug ? Have permission but getScanResults() still return empty list in Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288416/android-6-0-bug-have-permission-but-getscanresults-still-return-empty-list-i)

[The method checkSelfPermission(Context, String) is undefined for the type ContextCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613002/the-method-checkselfpermissioncontext-string-is-undefined-for-the-type-contex)

[Wifi scan results broadcast receiver not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050101/wifi-scan-results-broadcast-receiver-not-working)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrrBlxq33ms&t=181s

Please try my code and see if it runs on your device and if it give the list of Access Points. If not please advice. Thanks in advance

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Switch aSwitch;
WifiManager wifiManager;
TextView textView;
//Context mContext;

private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //mContext = (Manifest.permission) this;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.myswitch);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    //reg switch
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        checkPermission();
    }

    aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //to switch on
            if (isChecked && !wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
            } else if (!isChecked && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
              wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
       }
    });

    //WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    //textView.setText("\n\n Wifi status: " + wifiInfo.toString());


}

private boolean checkPermission() {

    List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE);
    }

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS:
            if (permissions.length == 1 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                    (permissions.length == 2 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)){
                onContinue();
            }
            else {
                // Permission Denied
                //Usually it works and I am thinking to add a toast later on
            }
            break;
    }
}



//@Override
void onContinue() {
    MyBroadCastReceiver myBroadCastReceiver = new MyBroadCastReceiver();
    // register WiFi scan results receiver
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(myBroadCastReceiver, filter);
    wifiManager.startScan();
    super.onResume();
}

class MyBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        List<ScanResult> scanResults = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        if (scanResults != null && !scanResults.isEmpty()) {
            for (ScanResult scanResult : scanResults) {
                stringBuffer.append(scanResult);
            }
            textView.setText(stringBuffer);

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Why do you want us to try your code? Is your code not working, or do you get an error?