# myWifiManager.getScanResults() returns list of size 0

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I am trying to find the all access points nearby me using a Android application.
 So i have scanned them  using WifiManager. Prior to this process i have enabled wifi and registered a BroadCasterReceiver.But It returns the list of access points with zero size.
Below is the snippet of code on Activity startup

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      myWifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
      WifiReceiver receiverwifi = new WifiReceiver();
      myWifiManager.startScan();
      IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter();
      i.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
      registerReceiver(receiverwifi,i);
}
```

And Below is the code of BroadCasterReceiver

```
class WifiReceiver extends  BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction()) && myWifiManager.startScan() && myWifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){
            List<ScanResult> scans= myWifiManager.getScanResults();
            System.out.println("size of list is "+ scans.size());
            //Remaining code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must have GPS enabled and permission for it. It's a known bug which have already submitted to Google.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34288416/android-6-0-bug-have-permission-but-getscanresults-still-return-empty-list-i)

Comment: @Sanoop i have added all the required permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Do we have to additionally check the permissions if they are granted or not ?

Comment: Thanks a lot...It was really very helpful !!!

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. For my case, my application already needed GPS, so i had to ask the permissions. But i think it might even work when GPS is enabled and app doesnt require the permission. (I havent tried this way).

Comment: I tried with run time permissions in addition to added permissions in xml and turned on  device gps  ... it worked smoothly.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Happy coding